# I have a very long and repetitive python path, where do I look to correct this?

Tags: python, shell, path, development-environment, pythonpath

I know it is probably not necessary to paste the whole path, but just for the record I have done so below. Whenever I run a python command, it takes a long time to load this path I suppose. I have checked in .bash_profile and only have these two lines:

export PATH=/Users/username/bin:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/apache2/bin:$PATH

export PYTHONPATH=/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/

And my python path as outputed by Django's debug is:

Python path : ['/Users/username/Sites/videocluster/eggs/ipython-0.10-py2.5.egg', '/Users/username/Sites/videocluster/eggs/South-0.6.1-py2.5.egg', '/Users/username/Sites/videocluster/eggs/django_markitup-0.5.2-py2.5.egg', '/Users/username/Sites/videocluster/eggs/DateTime-2.12.0-py2.5.egg', '/Users/username/Sites/videocluster/eggs/Markdown-2.0.3-py2.5.egg', '/Users/username/Sites/videocluster/eggs/PIL-1.1.7-py2.5-macosx-10.5-i386.egg', '/Users/username/Sites/videocluster/eggs/djangorecipe-0.20-py2.5.egg', '/Users/username/Sites/videocluster/eggs/zc.recipe.egg-1.2.3b2-py2.5.egg', '/Users/username/Sites/videocluster/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.0b2-py2.5.egg', '/Users/username/Sites/videocluster/eggs/pytz-2010h-py2.5.egg', '/Users/username/Sites/videocluster/eggs/zope.interface-3.6.1-py2.5-macosx-10.5-i386.egg', '/Users/username/Sites/videocluster/eggs/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/Users/username/Sites/videocluster/parts/django', '/Users/username/Sites/videocluster', '/Users/username/Sites/videocluster/bin', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools_git-0.3.3-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/pysqlite-2.5.5-py2.5-macosx-10.5-i386.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/CouchDB-0.5-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/httplib2-0.4.0-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/PyYAML-3.08-py2.5-macosx-10.5-i386.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/simple_db_migrate-1.2.8-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/PyDispatcher-2.0.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/pyOpenSSL-0.9-py2.5-macosx-10.5-i386.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/greenlet-0.2-py2.5-macosx-10.5-i386.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Supay-0.0.2-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/configobj-4.6.0-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Fabric-0.9b1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/fudge-0.9.3-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/pydelicious-0.5.3-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/feedparser-4.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/github_cli-0.2.5.2-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/simplejson-2.0.9-py2.5-macosx-10.5-i386.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg',        ......(repeating).......      '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/harobed.paster_template.advanced_package-0.2-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/squash-0.5.0dev-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/eventlet-0.8.13-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/FeinCMS-1.0.2-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/pyenchant-1.5.3-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/guppy-0.1.9-py2.5-macosx-10.5-i386.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django_scraper-0.1dev-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Pympler-0.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/fabric.contrib.packagemanager-0.1dev-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.4.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/selenium-1.0.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Scrapy-0.9_dev-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.4.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.4.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.4.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.4.1-py2.5.egg',     ......(repeating).......     '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.4.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.4.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.4.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.4.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.4.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.4.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.4.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.4.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.4.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.4.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.4.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.4.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.4.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.4.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.4.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.4.1-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python25.zip', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/plat-darwin', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/plat-mac', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/lib-tk', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Numeric', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/PIL', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/PIL', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0',      ......(repeating).......      '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0']

Someone, please tell me where I can go to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably some files with extension `.pth` presumably in site-packages that add things to sys.path.  This would explain (and let you fix) everything except the repetitions, which your site.py should actually eliminate (did you perhaps change site.py?  Nobody ever does or should, but ...

If site.py is unbroken, the only explanation is that some other code running after site.py is doing a sys.path.append in a too-enthusiastic loop.  "grepping" might help find the culprit.  Until you do, a simple bandaid on the wound is to run a simple "uniquifier" as soon as you can to remove the duplicates:

```
  done = set()
  newp = []
  for p in sys.path:
    if p in done: continue
    newp.append(p)
    done.add(p)
  sys.path = newp
```

Comment: yes you are right. In site-packages there are .pth files that add stuff like:

import sys,new,os; p = os.path.join(sys._getframe(1).f_locals['sitedir'], *('paste',)); ie = os.path.exists(os.path.join(p,'__init__.py')); m = not ie and sys.modules.setdefault('paste',new.module('paste')); mp = (m or []) and m.__dict__.setdefault('__path__',[]); (p not in mp) and mp.append(p)

Is it safe to take all that off without breaking anything else?

Comment: @ninja123, if you take "things" off sys.path (except duplicates) you will break anything that counts on being able to import from those "things", of course (that's why they've been put on sys.path when you installed all of those eggs &c).

Comment: Yea, i figured the stuff in .pth is not what is adding the repetitions. Its some code in site.py that is messed up. How can I get a fresh copy of site.py?

Comment: The latest 2.5 one is at http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release25-maint/Lib/site.py?revision=51333&view=markup (hit download from there) but while it's worth trying I think it may not fix you problem (which may be due to code running _after_ site.py is done).

Comment: You are right, the problem is with code after site.py. I have tried everything I could but couldn't resolve the issue. You said "grepping" might help to find the culprit. How would I go about doing that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually putting your four lines of code into site-packages/site.py now solves the problem. I am wondering why there aren't already any measures to avoid repeated modules from loading into sys.path?

Comment: @ninja, there _are_ -- see function `removeduppaths` in site.py (it's called right at the start of site's `main` function). Mystery  is, why doesn't it get executed in your case!  Anyway, `grep`ping means searching for strings and regular expressions inside text files with the good old Unix command `grep` ("Global Regular Expression Print") or by extension with any other similar engine, editor, etc.